# ADDING MYSQL INTO NODE.JS PROJECT DOESNT WORK ON THE NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, connection

After node.js server is executed localhost web server are launched inside html page is a game where after lets say user press button ball spawns and he can drop on +50 +1 +10 slots and then add that data to mysql database and show top 5 players.

Function where i need to add mysql to send data after ball hit specified target.
" I have added myself and it's not sending data."

```
function addGiftItem(data) {
   
       let container = $('.giftcontainer');
   
       if (container.find('div').length > 200) {
           container.find('div').slice(0, 100).remove();
       }
   
       let streakId = data.userId.toString() + '_' + data.giftId;
   
       let html = `
   
   <script>
   
   function getBucket(chip) {
   
   let mysql = require('mysql');
   var connection = mysql.createConnection( {
     host : 'localhost',
     user : 'root',
     password : '441441',
     database : 'app'
   } );
   
       var total = 0;
       $.each(chip.path, function(i, e) {
           total += e;
       });
   
   
   
   
       switch(total) {
   
           case -4:
            // alert("+50");
   try {
   connection.connect()
   var queryString = "insert into top5(Name,Score) values('${data.describe}',50)";
   connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
   });
   connection.end();
   
   }
   catch(err) {
   alert("err2")
   }
   
               break;
   
           case -2:
           //  alert("+1");
   try {
   connection.connect()
   var queryString = "insert into top5(Name,Score) values('${data.describe}',1)";
   connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
   });
   connection.end();
   
   }
   catch(err) {
   alert("err2")
   }
               break;
   
           case 0:
           //  alert("+10");
   try {
   connection.connect()
   var queryString = "insert into top5(Name,Score) values('${data.describe}',10)";
   connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
   });
   connection.end();
   
   }
   catch(err) {
   alert("err2")
   }
               break;
   
           case 2:
           //  alert("+1");
   try {
   connection.connect()
   var queryString = "insert into top5(Name,Score) values('${data.describe}',1)";
   connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
   });
   connection.end();
   
   }
   catch(err) {
   alert("err2")
   }
               break;
   
           case 4:
           //  alert("+50");
   try {
   connection.connect()
   var queryString = "insert into top5(Name,Score) values('${data.describe}',50)";
   connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
   });
   connection.end();
   
   }
   catch(err) {
   alert("err2")
   }
               break;
   
           default:
               break;
       }   
       
           $(chip.el).remove();
   }
   
   </script>
   
           <div data-streakid=${isPendingStreak(data) ? streakId : ''}>
               <img class="miniprofilepicture" src="${data.profilePictureUrl}">
               <span>
                   <b>${generateUsernameLink(data)}:</b> <span>${data.describe}</span><br>
                   <div>
                       <table>
                           <tr>
                               <td><img class="gifticon" src="${data.giftPictureUrl}"></td>
                               <td>
                                   <span>Name: <b>${data.giftName}</b> (ID:${data.giftId})<span><br>
                                   <span>Repeat: <b style="${isPendingStreak(data) ? 'color:red' : ''}">x${data.repeatCount.toLocaleString()}</b><span><br>
                                   <span>Cost: <b>${(data.diamondCount * data.repeatCount).toLocaleString()} Diamonds</b><span>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </tabl>
                   </div>
               </span>
           </div>
   
   
   <script>
   try {
   
   var chip = $('<div style="z-index:9;" class="chip"><img id="round" style="position: relative;right: 30px;bottom: 30px;z-index:999;" class="rounded" src="${data.profilePictureUrl}" width="50px" hight="50px"></div>');
   var chip = new Chip('plinko-board', 1300);
   const func = () => setTimeout(chip.start(),500);
   const times = ${(data.diamondCount * data.repeatCount).toLocaleString()};
   Array.from({length: times}, () => func());
   }
   catch(err) {
     alert("err");
   }
   
   
   
   </script>
   
       `;
   
       let existingStreakItem = container.find(`[data-streakid='${streakId}']`);
   
       if (existingStreakItem.length) {
           existingStreakItem.replaceWith(html);
       } else {
           container.append(html);
       }
   
   
       container.stop();
       container.animate({
           scrollTop: container[0].scrollHeight
       }, 800);
   }
```

Problem is that mysql doesnt send data to mysql database after adding into node.js project. But if I run code below on node.js server without adding into project on seperate file it sends data!

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
   var connection = mysql.createConnection( {
     host : 'localhost',
     user : 'root',
     password : '441441',
     database : 'app'
   } );

 connection.connect() 
var queryString = "insert into top5(Name,Score) values('${data.describe}',10)"; connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) { }); 
connection.end();
```

Comment: What is your question here? You posted a bunch of code and a vague explanation of what the application does.

Comment: UPDATED ! with more information so u can understand.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run the mysql code on the client side. You can't do that. Also, constructing a new script like that inside of an event handler is just a massively bad idea. Simplify your code.

Comment: maybe u can simplify for me this time so other time i can learn from your example how to simplify.